# Using a proxy to direct requests to backend vs using a different env?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, build, environment-variables

I have a React application that reaches out to an API hosted on a different machine. The address of the machine hosting the backend will change from client to client. I currently use a script that builds a version of the React application with different env's for each of the clients. However as the number of clients is increasing, so is the number distinct builds I need to support.

My question is then: Which is preferable, continuing with my approach of one set of env's per client, or using a proxy (likely nginx) to redirect requests to the backend and making the setup of the proxy something for the client to do?

My only concern thus far with the second approach is that it means that nginx will be running in production, but not in development - which could potentially lead to production only issues that are difficult to resolve.

Comment: Those aren't the only two options, but in general I wouldn't recommend the build time configuration. It means you're actually deploying a different artefact to each environment, maybe not even all built at the same time, rather than promoting already-tested code into production.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @jonrsharpe! What are some other options I should investigate?

Comment: Either service discovery patterns, or externalise the config to a single trivial JS (https://github.com/pivotal/postfacto/tree/master/web/public), JSON or HTML (https://github.com/spa-configuration/react-ssi) file you can easily switch out or generate (a post by my colleague on this: https://timysewyn.be/blog/2017-12-27-Deploying-web-applications-with-environment-specific-configurations/) for each environment.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the pointers!